# DNS name of Google Cloud Virtual Machine

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

I have few VMs running on **Microsoft Azure**. The VM gets a DNS name assigned something like `mytestvm.cloudapp.net`

With this DNS name, I can access services running on that VM.

Now, I am trying to get the same on **Google Cloud**.
I am unable to find anything like this.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Please suggest.

Comment: GCE VMs only get a default host name based on their instance name, zone, and project for their internal IPs (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns)). You would need to provide your own DNS (for example, by using Cloud DNS) to connect to the external IP by hostname.